# Mapear tabelas para guardar histórico de acesso

Tags: android, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mobile

Possuo um aplicativo, no qual preciso guardar ao menos uma vez no dia, a data e o horário que usuário acessou o aplicativo/sistema. Pois cobramos ao final do mês pelo número de dias que esse utilizou o app/software.

Qual a melhor forma de mapear essa tabela?

Comment: Uma tabela LogAcesso com o Id do Usuário, Data / Hora e Ip não seria suficiente? Daí toda vez que o usuário efetuar Logon, você salva essas informações na tabela Log de Acesso.

Comment: Estou pensando no volume de dados, porque isso teria que ser feito para todos os dias do ano e nas consultas eu deveria separar por mês.

Comment: Quanto ao volume de dados não vejo problema pois você pode trabalhar com um banco NoSQL! Mesmo com um banco de dados relacional, você teria que ter muito, mas muito registro mesmo para começar a pensar em performance!

Comment: Você utiliza WebApi para servir seu app?

Comment: @miltoncamara utilizo um serviço de backend similar ao firebase.

Comment: Então fique tranquilo, pois esses serviços aguentam uma boa quantidade de dados, no meu caso eu utilizo o Azure Document DB e funciona muito bem!

Comment: @miltoncamara Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que para isso você possa criar uma tabela bem simples com as colunas:

- ID do usuário que esta acessando
- data e hora.

Em algumas aplicações que crio costumo separar a coluna de data em duas colunas, uma somente com a data e outra com horas e minutos, pois assim acaba facilitando em algumas consultas.

Não existe uma 'melhor forma" de mapear uma tabela mas sim uma melhor forma que atenderá sua aplicação.